# JavaScript arithmetic subtraction giving extra unwanted decimal digits

Tags: javascript, subtraction

```
var a = 8.4286;
var b = 2;
console.log(a-b)
```

Actual Output:  `6.428599999999999`

Expected Output: `6.4286`

What is the reason behind this and how to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.toFixed`:

```js
var a = 8.4286;
var b = 2;
let sub = a-b;
sub = sub.toFixed(4);
console.log(sub);
```

Comment: The same question is already asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken as `parseFloat((a - b).toFixed(4));` where 4 is the number of decimal digits wanted.